# How to modify the rooms module?

Tags: 7, blocks

I'm testing the [rooms](http://drupal.org/project/rooms) module. It's a great module.

It has a page to **performs a searches to get availability information of the rooms** (mysite/booking) . I need this page to be available as a block.
So that I can put the searcher anywhere.

Anyone using this module to help to do it?

**I just found how to get the block.** But now I can't get the validation working properly. If date are no chosen an error page is shown.

**Any help please?**

I think it could be very useful to have this block working properly.

Look for the file: rooms/modules/rooms_booking_manager/rooms_booking_manager.module

At the end add this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
 function rooms_booking_manager_block_info() {
  $blocks['booking_searcher'] = array(
    'info' => t('Room Booking Manager'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;   
}


/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function rooms_booking_manager_block_view($delta = '') {
  if (user_access('access rooms_booking_manager blocks')) {
    $block = array();

        // Prepare to return the $block variable with subject (title) and content (output).
        $block['subject'] = 'Search block';
        $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('rooms_booking_availability_search_form');

    return $block;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but I do want to say this: Do yourself a favor and, instead of changing the rooms module, add your block in a separate custom module. This will allow you to do everything you can do in rooms itself, but it will make it much easier to take advantage of future updates.

Comment: You are right, but I'll need to learn to create that module.

Comment: @chefnelone I learned Drupal by myself a few years ago and trust me, it's easy, there's no much more to it than creating a folder, a .info file, and a .module file. The world is yours afterwards ;)

Comment: [This tutorial on D.O.](http://drupal.org/node/1074360) will walk you thru all the steps in creating a custom block in a custom module. Once you've read it, you can re-edit your question and ask for help with any problems that you could have stumbled upon.